# Linking CSS Stylesheet not working

Tags: php, html, css

I have two CSS links in the head of my PHP file.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/style.css">
```

The first one (Bootstrap) works. The second one doesn't. They are both in the same path. I've double and triple checked that the second one is spelled correctly. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: show file structure on css

Comment: clear cache maybe

Comment: Use `view page source` option in browser...check the path of that css file

Comment: Also check the second one for errors

Comment: There aren't any errors when I check

Comment: CTRL-F5, what happens?

Comment: Use browser to inspect which css is being applied

Comment: Check the network tab ? Does it shows 404 ?

Comment: Perhaps you can send ur html and tell us what class you want to apply

Comment: No class I'm just testing by trying to turn the h1 tags to red

Comment: I used view page source and I clicked on the css file and it returned the content I had written!

Comment: CTRL+F5 = nothing

Comment: inspect the element you are adding style to. Maybe its overwritten by some other file.

Comment: maybe you have a rule that is not being set, so try to add `!important` to some of them, or you have an inline style happening in HTML somewhere.

Comment: Does it work when you remove the first css link rel tag?

Comment: No starkeen it still doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

**Check the location of your file in a web site's folder structure.**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
css is located in the same folder as the current page

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
css is located in the styles folder in the current folder

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/bootstrap.min.css">    
css is located in the styles folder at the root of the current web

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/bootstrap.min.css">  
css is located in the folder one level up from the current folder
```